# Preselect point in google charts

Tags: javascript, html, graphics, charts

currently I'm using google charts and I have a quick question. Is it possible to render a graph with a certain point preselected instead of having to click on a point in order to make it "stand out".

So that the bellow is automatically visible when rendered for example.

[image]

https://developers.google.com/chart/interactive/docs/gallery/linechart

Answer (score 0):

Use the [Chart's `setSelection()` method](https://developers.google.com/chart/interactive/docs/reference?hl=ja#vissetselection) to pre-select a point.

Comment: Does indeed select but does not apply the border to tell the user it's selected

Answer (score -1):

Put the default values inside the array of this function and that will be pre selected.

```
function drawChart() {
    var data = google.visualization.arrayToDataTable([
      ['Year', 'Sales', 'Expenses'],
      ['2004',  1000,      400],
      ['2005',  1170,      460],
      ['2006',  660,       1120],
      ['2007',  1030,      540]
    ]);
```